# Square with largest sum in the matrix

Tags: algorithm

I've got quite typical problem, I think. I know there were similar topics here but understand that I'm a beginner and do not distinguish different versions of this problem. Sometimes little difference in text and the algorithm can be completely different.. So the problem is:

```
For a given 2<=a,b<=1000 and 1<=c<=Min(a,b) find in matrix a x b square c x c 
with the largest sum of elements. The elements in matrix are from -1000 to 1000.
```

I can write an algorithm that runs the entire matrix and on every point(x,y) it counts sum for a square (x,y), (x+c,y), (x,y+c), (x+c,y+c). Then I chose the largest sum. With these constraints I think it could be quite fast, but is there any faster algorithm? I'm not good at counting algorithm complexity but it seems to be O(a*b*c*c). And if I'm not wrong in the worst case it may not stop..

Comment: This sounds like a good problem for [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the right way to approach this is to do an integral transform first:  for each element (i,j) of the original matrix M, compute integral transform matrix `I(i,j) = sum[0..i, 0..j](M)`.  By running sums in both the rows and columns directions, you can do this in O(a*b) time.

Once you have the integral transform, you can compute the sum of *any sub-block* in constant time as:

```
sum[i0..i1, j0..j1](M) = I(i1,j1) - I(i0 - 1, j1) - I(i1, j0 - 1) + I(i0 - 1, j0 - 1)
```

so you can compute and compare each c x c square sum in constant time, for a total of O(a*b).

Comment: thank you, I like this approach.. didn't know about such trick, very useful, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will work and you are right about the time complexity, indeed it is a*b*c*c.
One way to speed up a little bit is that, when you slide the c*c window, you don't re-compute everything, but only subtract the ones that are moving out of the window and add the ones that are moving in to the window. Since you can do this on both direction x and direction y, you may want to remember the sums of all c*c squares in a column (or in a row) for future look-up.

Answer (score 1):

I think with the sliding approach mentioned here, your complexity is reduced.
So assuming in your case, a,b,c are constant in each optimization problem (meaning c is not an optimizing variable).

1) start from the upper left corner, O(c*c)

2) slide to the right O(c) after removing the leftmost column and adding the rightmost column

3) repeat (2) for (a-c) times, so O(c*(a-c))

4) (1)-(3) cost about O(c*c + c*(a-c))

5) you also need to slide down and do this for the other (b-c) rows, each of them cost O(c) to  slide down and O(c*a) to complete a row, which in total is O( c*c + c*(a-c)*(b-c) + c*(a-c) + c*(b-c) )

6) assuming a,b>>c, it can simplify to O(b*c*a)

Let me know if there is anything wrong!

Comment: comingstorm is right, what I have here would be the complexity if the c*c mask is not uniform